# Automatic drive backups

Tags: windows, backup

I have just had a scare of losing $50,000 worth of work. Are there any software for Windows which automatically create backups?

I would like to back up my drive every hour. But daily back ups will be sufficient enough.

I could write a program to do this for me in C++, but there is no point since I know there is probably already a software out there.

Comment: Need a program = http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
Need help with a program = http://superuser.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't mind a monthly fee of approx $9/month (quantity discount available) then use CrashPlan.  It what I use.

Comment: Great suggestion! i just signed up

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built in backup program that can be scheduled to run. Go to Control Panel/Sytem and Security/Backup and Restore.  You can schedule [what files and how often](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) to backup. In addition, there are some third party vendors who provide similar products. The one I use is [Crashplan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/).  However, I don't like backing up to the "cloud".  Call me old fashion, but, I'm not convinced of the security online backups provide.  So, I set up an Ubuntu server that uses Crashplan to back up the pcs on my home network on a scheduled basis.

Comment: your answer was okay... but you didn't provide any of the software.. but i still voted up :) cheers!

Comment: Once again mystery down votes. .. got to love this place.

Comment: Can you expand this answer? You've provided very little useful information here.

Comment: @DragonLord Per you request, I've expanded my response.